# PHP not sending any data with POST

Tags: php, xampp

I have this simple code:

```
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="titleDiv">
                <h1>Image canvas</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="previewDiv">
                <img src="#" id="imgPreview">
            </div>
            <div class="buttonsDiv">
                <button type="button" class="rotateButtons" id="rotateLeft">
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> Rotate left
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="uploadDiv">
                <form action="upload.php" method="POST" id="#uploadForm">
                    <!--<input type="file" name="img" accept="image/*" id="imgUpload">-->
                    <input type="number" name="number" value="0">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And on the `upload.php` file I have only 2 lines of code:

```
    var_dump($_POST);
    var_dump($_GET);
```

When I try to send this data over POST I get an output `array(0) { }` .
Though when I change the form method to `method="GET"` everything works normal and I receive the the data great on the `upload.php`.

I looked the php.ini file (I am using xampp as a local server) and the line `;enable_post_data_reading=Off` is commented. Can someone help sort out this problem?

Comment: Do you somehow have a redirect? Because then the post variables will be lost. Open your develop console (on chrome) and check the network tab. If the request returns a 3xx then that might be the problem.

Comment: I just did, I am getting a 200 status which means the status is OK

Comment: Try to inspect the network traffic with your browser's examine or developer tools. Are the correct values sent with the headers?

Comment: Try to uncomment that 'enable_post_data_reading=Off' and put 'enable_post_data_reading=true'..i think it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you're actually using your webserver. What's the address on your navigation bar? It should be localhost without some strange ports. If it's pointing to 63342 that could be your problem.

edit: that could happen if you're using an IDE

Comment: Yes I had the 63342 code on my localhost, when I removed it, the data send without problem. I am using PHPStorm as an IDE. I will try to find a way to configure it.

Comment: The IDE is using it's built in web server. To test properly you could probably just access your browser directly with the correct address. ;)